# C++: Fastest way to copy a section of doubles

Tags: c++, optimization

Currently I have the following code to copy some doubles to a different vector of doubles.

```
for (int i = 0;i<=iTo;i++)
{

    int iID= i + iOff;
    double d=m[iID];
    uTargets[iSamplePos]=d;
    iSamplePos++;
}
```

Can somebody tell me the fastest way to do this without the "manual" iteration?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're overwriting an existing vector:

```
uTargets.assign(m.begin() + iOff, m.begin() + iOff + iTo + 1);
```

If you're copying into a range that already exists:

```
std::copy(m.begin() + iOff, m.begin() + iOff + iTo + 1, uTargets.begin() + iSamplePos);
```

Comment: Why would std::copy be any different? Surely it must do what the OP has done in his question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use memcpy(uTargets,m+iOFF,(iTo-iOff+1)*sizeof(double));
But I would stick with more reliable methods like iterations or std::copy, unless you need to copy a really large amount of memory.

Comment: memcpy will always be the fastest way.

Comment: And often unwarranted. People use it sometimes to copy just several values. It's very easy to swap src and dst or to write out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the documentation for the [algorithm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) portion of the C++ Standard Library.

> The algorithms library defines functions for a variety of purposes
>   (e.g. searching, sorting, counting, manipulating) that operate on
>   ranges of elements. Note that a range is defined as [first, last)
>   where last refers to the element past the last element to inspect or
>   modify.

In general, for operations like traversing containers in different ways and applying certain kind of transformations to their elements, you should rely on the standard interface.

In your particular case, you mention you have two vectors (by which I assume you mean objects of class `std::vector<T>`).

As other have mentioned, you can use the algorithm `std::copy`, which takes the following syntax:

```
std::copy(source.begin(), source.end(), destination.begin())
```

Now, you have to be careful here. This assumes that `destination` already has reserved the space. That is, somewhere before that line you created destination as:

```
std::vector<double> destination(source.size());
```

If that is not the case, you can use a kind of iterator called a "back inserter".

The following example can shed some light (notice that `std::iota` simply fills a container with a sequence (e.g., k, k++, k++, ...))

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iterator>

void show(const char* name, std::vector<double>& v) {
  std::cout<<"Vector '"<<name<<"'"<<std::endl;
  for(auto & item : v) {
    std::cout<<item<<" ";
  }
  std::cout<<std::endl;
}

int main() {
  // create a vector to store twenty doubles
  std::vector<double> source(20);
  // fill with the numbers 0, 1, ..., 19
  std::iota(source.begin(), source.end(), 0);

  // let's peek 
  show("Source", source);

  // create a destination vector capable of holding the values
  std::vector<double> destination_1(source.size());
  // copy the values
  std::copy(source.begin(), source.end(), destination_1.begin());

  show("Destination 1", destination_1);

  // create a destination vector without space reserved
  std::vector<double> destination_2;
  // copy the values (use the back inserter)
  std::copy(source.begin(), source.end(), std::back_inserter(destination_2));

  show("Destination 2", destination_2);

  return 0;
}
```

Output (compiled with g++ 4.7.2 using C++11 support, i.e., `c++ file.cpp -std=c++11`):

```
Vector 'Source'
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
Vector 'Destination 1'
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
Vector 'Destination 2'
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
```